# Banach-Mazur distance

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am stuck upon the following problem. Consider the Banach-Mazur distance for $X$ ,$Y$ normed isomorphic vector spaces
$$d(X,Y) = \inf \{ \| T \| \| T^{-1} \| : T \in GL(X,Y) \}$$
I would like to prove, for $\ell_p^n = (\mathbb R^n, \| \cdot \|_p )$, that
$$d(\ell_1^n, \ell_2^n)\ge \sqrt n$$
without John's Theorem or volume inequalities. Can anybody lend a hand?

Thank you ever so much.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose $T:\ell_1^n\to \ell_2^n$ is an operator of norm $1$. Let  $e_1,\dots,e_n$ be the standard basis of $\ell_1^n$. By our assumption $\|Te_j\|_2\le 1$ for all $j$.

There are $2^n$ vectors of the form $\sum_{j=1}^n \pm e_j$. Each of them has $\ell_1$ norm $n$. 
On the other hand, summing $\left\|\sum_{j=1}^n \pm Te_j \right\|_2^2$ over all choices of signs and expressing the Euclidean norm via an inner product, we get cancellation leading to
 $$\sum_{\pm} \left\|\sum_{j=1}^n \pm Te_j \right\|_2^2
=2^n  \sum_{j=1}^n \|Te_j \|_2^2 \le 2^n n 
 $$ 
Thus, there is a vector of the form $x=\sum_{j=1}^n \pm  e_j$ such that  $\|Tx\|_2\le \sqrt{n}$. This proves $\|T^{-1}\|\ge \sqrt{n}$.

Comment: I fail to see the last assert. I think we lack normalizing $x$.

Comment: @D... Line 3 says $\|x\|_1=n$.